# Pl SQL procedure for getting data from one table to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Cursor c1 is select uid,h1,h2,h3 from             xyz;
   Begin
     For I in c1
      Loop
       Insert into ABC                  .         values(i.uid,I.h1
            ||/||I.h2
               ||/||I.h3);
      End loop;
   End;
```

Comment: please give more details and be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can do what you're trying to accomplish in a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO XYZ
  SELECT UID, H1 || '/' || H2 || '/' || H3;
```

Best of luck.